# Write file from remote server to local directory?

Tags: unix, grep, remote, scp

I want to do some grep-magic to a logfile on a remote server and write the result to a local file on my computer.

Is there an easier way than my 3 step solution:

1. do `grep`-magic and write file on remote server
2. copy from remote to local with `scp`
3. delete the file on remote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute the command in the remote server through `ssh` and store the output locally:

```
ssh myuser@thatserver 'grep "aa"' > ~/myoutput.res
```